# Calculated properties with service reference

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api, data-binding, odata

I have a WinForms app which uses a Web API (ODATA) server for its data sources.  I am binding grids and forms to proxy classes of the service reference.

In some UI fields I need to display calculated values.  If I were writing a "standard" WinForms app (without using a service reference and its proxy classes), I would bind to business objects that populate themselves from SQL and let those business objects expose the calculated properties so that I could bind to them from the UI.  For example:

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    (many other properties here...)
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get { return Quantity * Price; } }
}
```

I can now do my data binding to Total whereever needed.

But I do not see how to do this when using classes in auto-created service reference proxy classes as the databinding source.

I could of course create local business objects for the databinding and then use these to populate service reference objects when it is time to persist the data or I could do the calculation in the UI (e.g. in the OnChange event [or similar] for the Quantity or Price), but I would rather not if there is a better way.  Both lead to code duplication.

*What is a good way to deal with calculated properties in this scenario?*

Comment: At least you can use partial model classes.

Comment: But what doe you mean by auto-created service reference proxy classes? How do you use ASP.NET Web Api services? Or are you using WCF services?

Comment: @Reza Aghei You can add a service reference in Visual Studio for a Web API service that implements ODATA v3 much like you would do with WCF.  E.g.: http://localhost:63957/odata

Comment: @reza-aghaei Partial model classes sounds like a good idea!  Let me take it for a spin...

Answer (score 1):

Proxy model classes will be generated as `partial` classes. So you can create a partial model class and add the calculated property. For example:

```
namespace ProductServiceClient.ServiceReference1
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        public decimal SomeProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Price * 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The namespace is your application default namespace + service reference namespace which you set in Add reference dialog.

[Here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client) is a good example for creating a service and service client for those who want to reproduce and solve the problem with minimal effort.

Comment: @reze-aghaei: Yes, this should work.  Note: you are missing the "partial" keyword in your answer.

Comment: @reze-aghaei: Even though this solution works on the client-side, it throws an exception on the server side: "The property SomeProperty does not exist on type Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."  I searched for an attribute or similar that can be used to not send the added properties from the partial class to the server, but there does not seem to be such an attribute.

Comment: @reze-aghaei:  ODATA v4 seems to have a solution (open types): https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4.  I am not thrilled about having to add a Dictionary property to a bunch of classes, but at least it should solve the issue.  I just need to find out if I can use ODATA v4 (I currently use v3).  But I am all ears if you can thing of something better.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lars335 Dynamic Properties are not typed. They are `object` and you should unbox the value yourself. Dynamic properties define this way: `public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }`. It seems you can not define calculated dynamic property.

Comment: @reze-aghaei: I got the impression that the untyped dictionary was used for containing any properties defined on the client that does not exist in the actual model, but I guess that is not the case.  So it will not work (and I also found out that I cannot use ODATA v4 anyhow).  There really seems to be no way to do calculated client-side properties, so it seems that I will have to do the calculation in UI event handlers instead.  Not pretty...

Comment: @Lars335 Why not using partial classes? (If you don't want to use view models and shaping the results to view models.)

Comment: @reze-aghaei: Because the properties on the partial class still get sent to the server where the model validation fails (ModelState.IsValid == false).  The message is, "The property 'SubTotal' does not exist on type 'AcmeService.Model.OrderEntry.Order'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."

Comment: @Lars335 Another evidence that the partial class probably is a good solution is partial methods which are generated in proxy model classes. For example for `Price` property of the `Product` class, `partial void OnPriceChanging(decimal value)` and `partial void OnPriceChanged()` is generted. It shows you can also provide implementation of those methods in a partial class.

Comment: @reze-aghae: what I really need is to add client-side calculated _properties_ (I cannot data-bind to a method) in such a way that server-side validation does not break.  If there were a way to prevent the added properties from being sent to the server it would work great.  Or even a clean, robust way to remove them server-side before the validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124915/discussion-between-lars335-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the [`TypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx) services to extend the model class with calculated properties.

In order to do that, you'll need some helper classes.

First, a generic class for a custom calculated property:

```
public class CalculatedProperty<TComponent, TValue> : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private Func<TComponent, TValue> func;
    public CalculatedProperty(string name, Func<TComponent, TValue> func)
        : base(name, null)
    {
        this.func = func;
    }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(TComponent); } }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return typeof(TValue); } }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override object GetValue(object component) { return func((TComponent)component); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
}
```

and a factory (to make it easier to use):

```
public static class CalculatedProperty
{
    public static PropertyDescriptor Create<TComponent, TValue>(string name, Func<TComponent, TValue> func)
    {
        return new CalculatedProperty<TComponent, TValue>(name, func);
    }
}
```

Next, in order to "add" properties to an existing class, you need a class that implements [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) interface and expose it via custom [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx). The process is a bit complicated, so I've encapsulated in the following class(es):

```
public class CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public static void Register(Type type, params PropertyDescriptor[] customProperties)
    {
        var baseProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(type);
        var typeDescriptor = new CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor(baseProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(type), customProperties);
        TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new Provider(baseProvider, typeDescriptor), type);
    }
    PropertyDescriptor[] customProperties;
    private CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor[] customProperties)
        : base(baseDescriptor)
    {
        this.customProperties = customProperties;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties() { return GetProperties(null); }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().Concat(customProperties).ToArray());
    }
    private class Provider : TypeDescriptionProvider
    {
        private CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor typeDescriptor;
        public Provider(TypeDescriptionProvider baseProvider, CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor typeDescriptor)
            : base(baseProvider)
        {
            this.typeDescriptor = typeDescriptor;
        }
        public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
        {
            return typeDescriptor;
        }
    }
}
```

That's all for the generic part. At the end, all you need is to call `CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor.Register` once at the application start for each class that needs calculated properties, providing them using the `CalculatedProperty.Create` method.

Here is an example:

*Model:* (Note there is no `Total` property)

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    (many other properties here...)
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

*Application:*

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        CustomPropertyTypeDescriptor.Register(typeof(OrderLine),
            CalculatedProperty.Create("Total", (OrderLine source) => source.Quantity * source.Price)
        );

        var form = new Form();
        var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
        dg.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n => new OrderLine
        {
            ItemNo = "Item#" + n,
            Quantity = n,
            Price = 10 * n
        }).ToList();

        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

*Result:* (Note the `Total` column)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure OData v4 Web API using the StructuralTypes.

Given the poster's original POCO model

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    (many other properties here...)
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get { return Quantity * Price; } }
}
```

You can use the StructuralTypes to modify the model and add back in the read only property.   The logical/calculated property will not exist in the physical database but will still be displayed in the OData service.

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<OrderLine>("OrderLines");

builder.StructuralTypes
    .First(t => t.ClrType == typeof(OrderLine))
    .AddProperty(typeof(OrderLine).GetProperty("Total"));

config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

You can take this further if you're source (existing) db that doesn't match the business requirements for the projected OData schema.  First add the following using's to your POCO class.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Then add the attributes to map your POCO class to the database schema, table name and column names.

```
[Table("Order_Line", Schema = "dbo")]
public class OrderLine
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ItemNo")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    (many other properties here...)

    [Column("Qty")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Column("Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal Total { get { return Quantity * Price; } }
}
```